# How to disable proxy for HTTP request to a specific IP

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, proxy, lan

On my LAN there is a proxy, web browsers on computers are configured to use that proxy.

I set up a server on my computer, and if others try to access it through my IP, their request goes to the proxy which will say that this server doesn't exist (because the proxy doesn't know my server).

Is there a solution to disable the use of the proxy for a specific domain/IP? That could be a system configuration, a Firefox/Chrome plugin, etc...

Comment: Do you know how they are configured to use a proxy? Different proxy configuration methods have different ways to disable it for certain sites. [PAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config)/[WPAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol) is probably the most difficult one, since you would have to change the PAC script on the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browsers allow you to configure which hosts are local, those hosts won't use the proxy. See the firefox example here (specifically the *No Proxy for:* input box)

[image: Firefox proxy settings]

Comment: And to cover all possible private (local) IPv4 addresses, at least in configurations that support CIDR notation, add `10.0.0.0/8`, `172.16.0.0/12` and `192.168.0.0/16`. Also worth adding is `169.254.0.0/16`: link-local, assigned randomly when no static address is specified and no DHCP server is available.

Comment: Yes! That did it, I found an equivalent configuration for Chrome, but it works, thanks.